# Tools for generate sequence diagram(UML) from PHP class(files)

Tags: php, uml, sequence, diagram

I want a tool to help me generate sequence diagram from PHP class,
is there any tools?
free or open source software will be prefered. THX~~~

UPDATE: And it must has Mac supported.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I will prefer [UML](http://www.websequencediagrams.com/) diagram.
You can draw the diagram with the flow.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to generate sequence diagrams capturing execution flows for documentation and debugging you can use this tool :

http://rattias.github.io/mscviewer/

Answer (score 0):

you can use this tool to generate PlantUML sequence diagrams based on the execution flow of a PHP application:

https://github.com/desjob/callgrind-to-plantuml-sequence-diagram

it requires recording with the XDebug profiler, and can generate images too.